# _tkinter.TclError: bad screen distance when using values of columns for coordinates from a row in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have got this row using `desired_row = data[data.state==answer]`

```
   state    x   y
34  Ohio  176  52
```

and when I do `turtle.goto((desired_row.x),(desired_row.y))` statement
I am getting error of bad screen distance. What is wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Values of state , x and y all are of string type.
You can simply convert values of x and y into integer to use them as coordinates.
Something like this

```
turtle.goto(int(desired_row.x),int(desired_row.y))
```